# is there any specific way or algorithm to verify if a function is uniformly continuous or not?

Tags: uniform-continuity

I want to know like for continuity of a function at a given point we can check the limit of the function at that point and the value of the function at that point but how to verify if a function is uniformly continuous or not over a given interval and all kind of interval that is for open , closed and semi open or closed interval